# How do I do a running year for a calendar report?

Tags: date

Here is the Query I am using:

```
SELECT * FROM ra_ProjectCalendar 
WHERE MonthNumber between @Month and @Month + 12 and FullYear = @Year
```

It works great for this year, but, stops at December of this year. How do I get it to show a running year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM ra_ProjectCalendar 
WHERE 
  (MonthNumber > @Month AND FullYear = @Year)
  OR (MonthNumber < @Month AND FullYear = @Year + 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

how is your date stored?

from your sql, i guess that you have one field for month, one for year and one for day. i'd recommend having one single datetime field instead, and then you can use the [DateAdd()](http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/da-db_5.htm) method to add 12 months (or any other interval).

EDIT: it was pointed out to me in a comment that one thing you gain on this is performance - which is more or less important depending on the scale of your applicaiton, but always nice to be aware of. if you run this query in a stored procedure, here's what you'll do:

```
DECLARE @oneYearAhead datetime;
SET @oneYearAhead = DateAdd(m, 12, @PassedDate)

SELECT * FROM ra_ProjectCalendar
 WHERE @PassedDate <= [Date] AND [Date] <= @oneYearAhead;
```

with the above code, you will get all entries between the date you pass, and one year ahead of it. (i am not 100% sure on the syntax to declare and set the `@oneYearAhead` variable, but you get the idea...). Note that the `[]` that i use around the column name Date allows me to use reserved words in column names - i have made it a habit, instead of memorizing which words are reserved...

Comment: Hmm, I like this because you can calculate the DateAdd() once before the query and then do a simple date compare rather than a function call in the where clause.  Show some code and I'll upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work better - but its not clear what your intent is:

```
select * 
 from ra_ProjectCalendar 
 where DATEDIFF ( month , @startdate , @enddate ) <=12
```

Edit: This is SQl server syntax

Answer (score 0):

Actually pass in and store the date rather than month and year, and compare with the current date using DateDiff:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(m, @PassedDate, StoredDateColumn) < 12
```

Note that I used 12 months, rather than 1 year, because DATEDIFF counts the number of boundries crossed.  So in december, using datediff with the year datepart would return one after only one month.  You really want a 12 month span.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your information is stored (it's a little difficult to tell from your query), either DATEADD or DATEDIFF will probably do you right. There's a list of the availabe [date functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337153(SQL.90).aspx) on MSDN.